# Design Pattern for Windows services

Tags: design-patterns, windows-services

I have been developing Windows services for more than 2 years.  I haven't tried any design patterns for this.  For my better professional growth, I'd like to follow design patterns for developing Windows services.  Can anyone suggest best suitable design pattern for the below requirement?

I have to write a Windows service which monitors a database table (oracle), retrieves the data from the table, parse it, create a file with the parsed data, and send the file location to a web service.

I appreciate your help in advance.

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe more what you mean by design pattern in the context of Windows Services? There are a number of simple frameworks out there that take care of most of the plumbing, and you just add your worker method.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are still very vague, and a design pattern is more a way to explain what is happening with fewer words.

So, for example, if you start with you want a window service that will use the singleton pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to call the database with a class using the data access object pattern (http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/jdbc/dataaccessobjectdesignpattern.html), then you may have some information.

If you look at Martin Fowler's site on some design patterns: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/

Look under *Data Source Architectural Patterns* and you will see four patterns that may help you, depending on how you want to interact with the database.